# How to pop up a text box(or tooltip) via script in Java

Tags: java, popup, tooltip, jna, jtooltip

I have a very specific question:
I want to be able to, via a method call, popup a tooltip with text(it could say anything) in a given location on the screen for a certain amount of time on method call(say the logic is in a talk method) and fades away. How could I go about that? Is there a way to do it via JTooltip? Or would I have to dive into JNA to get what I want?

I should mention I want the tooltip to popup with text in a given location without the cue of a mouse over, like a popup.

Also, in case a tooltip is not the right way to go about what I want (which I hope I made clear), is there a more effective alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways this might be achieved.  One possible way is through the use of a transparent `JWindow` and a Swing `Timer`

Basically, what this does is creates a `JWindow`, set's it's background color to fully transparent, making a transparent window.  It then uses simple `BackgroundPane` (to render a nice background) and `MessagePane` to hold the actual message.  You can do this in one panel, but I like the flexibility this affords me.

[image: Popup]

Now, personally, I would create a simpler API which could build the popup window and create a `Timer` with a variable delay, but you get the idea

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PopupMessageWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PopupMessageWindow();
    }

    public PopupMessageWindow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JWindow frame = new JWindow();
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                BackgroundPane pane = new BackgroundPane();
                pane.setMessage("Boo, This is a popup...");
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

                Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.dispose();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private MessagePane messagePane;

        public BackgroundPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 40, 40, 40));
            messagePane = new MessagePane();
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(messagePane);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void setMessage(String msg) {
            messagePane.setMessage(msg);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            LinearGradientPaint glp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                            new Point(0, 0),
                            new Point(0, getHeight()),
                            new float[]{0f, 1f},
                            new Color[]{Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK});
            RoundRectangle2D frame = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
            g2d.setPaint(glp);
            g2d.fill(frame);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.draw(frame);
        }

    }

    public class MessagePane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public MessagePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);
        }

        public void setMessage(String msg) {
            label.setText(msg);
        }

    }

}
```

You could play with a `AlphaComposite` on the background panel to create a semi transparent background

Popup window using a 50% `AlphaComposite`

[image: Popup]

**Updated**

You could use a factory or builder pattern to provide a simple API, for example...

```
new PopupBuilder().at(new Point(100, 100)).withMessage("Hello").withDelay(5000).show();
```

The builder would collect the properties you want to specify, provide defaults where you didn't set them and then would show the final popup.

The basic idea is when you call `show`, it would collect the properties and build the window similar to how the constructor works right now...

**Updated with a fading popup window**

This is (a somewhat over the top) example of how you might be able to produce a fading in/out effect.  The example guarantees that the message will be on the screen (full) for at specified delay period

[image: Popup]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PopupMessageExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PopupMessageExample();
    }

    public PopupMessageExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                new PopupMessageBuilder().withDelay(10000).withMessage("Hello, this is a fading message").show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class PopupMessageBuilder {

        private int delay;
        private Point location;
        private String message;

        private long startTime;
        private Timer fadeTimer;

        public PopupMessageBuilder at(Point p) {
            this.location = p;
            return this;
        }

        public PopupMessageBuilder withDelay(int delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
            return this;
        }

        public PopupMessageBuilder withMessage(String msg) {
            this.message = msg;
            return this;
        }

        public PopupMessageBuilder show() {

            final JWindow frame = new JWindow();
            frame.setOpacity(0f);
            frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            BackgroundPane pane = new BackgroundPane();
            pane.setMessage(message);
            frame.add(pane);
            frame.pack();
            if (location == null) {
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } else {
                frame.setLocation(location);
            }
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

            new FadeTimer(frame, 1000, 0f, 1f, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            new FadeTimer(frame, 1000, 1f, 0f, new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    frame.dispose();
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    });
                    timer.setRepeats(false);
                    timer.start();
                }
            }).start();

            return this;
        }

        public class FadeTimer extends Timer implements ActionListener {

            private final float startAt;
            private final float endAt;
            private final int duration;
            private long startTimer;

            private ActionListener endListener;

            private Window window;

            public FadeTimer(Window window, int duration, float startAt, float endAt, ActionListener endListener) {
                super(5, null);
                addActionListener(this);
                this.duration = duration;
                this.startAt = startAt;
                this.endAt = endAt;
                this.window = window;

                this.endListener = endListener;
            }

            @Override
            public void start() {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                super.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long lapsed = now - startTime;
                float opacity = startAt;
                if (lapsed >= duration) {
                    opacity = endAt;
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    if (endListener != null) {
                        endListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "stopped"));
                    }
                } else {
                    float progress = (float) lapsed / (float) duration;
                    float distance = endAt - startAt;
                    opacity = (float) (distance * progress);
                    opacity += startAt;
                }
                window.setOpacity(opacity);
            }

        }

        public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

            private MessagePane messagePane;

            public BackgroundPane() {
                setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 40, 40, 40));
                messagePane = new MessagePane();
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                add(messagePane);
                setOpaque(false);
            }

            public void setMessage(String msg) {
                messagePane.setMessage(msg);
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
                LinearGradientPaint glp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                                new Point(0, 0),
                                new Point(0, getHeight()),
                                new float[]{0f, 1f},
                                new Color[]{Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK});
                RoundRectangle2D frame = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
                g2d.setPaint(glp);
                g2d.fill(frame);
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.draw(frame);
            }

        }

        public class MessagePane extends JPanel {

            private JLabel label;

            public MessagePane() {
                setOpaque(false);
                label = new JLabel();
                label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                add(label);
            }

            public void setMessage(String msg) {
                label.setText(msg);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Now, you probably also do this by changing the maximum opacity level of the frame, but, if you change the `paintComponent` of the `BackgroundPane`

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    AlphaComposite alpha = AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.75f);
    g2d.setComposite(alpha);
```

you can also effect the over opacity of the popup message.  This method will only effect the background, not the message text...

Comment: I downloaded the code and tried it out, and for my purposes I think it works, however there is one problem. If I try to abstract parts of the code such that I can specify a quote and a location for the text bubble, I get a compiler error saying that since it uses inner classes, the parameters I pass in have to be declared final. Now the error itself is obvious, but I wonder how you would go about adding in the ability to specify a quote and location, given this setup. I could try to rehash this code entirely but I wonder if there's a way to do it preserving this architecture

Comment: As I mentioned, what it would actually do is create a factory class with one or more static methods. These would create the window and apply the message, much like the constructor does now. You can specify the location of the window by relpacing the setLocationRelativeTo method with setLocation on the window, the rest should already be setup to go...more or less ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it worked perfectly! I'm trying to get the alpha composite working, but I think I got lost at a step. I assume you try to apply the alpha composite in the background pane in the paint component method, affecting g2d, but whatever I did didn't have an effect on the transparency at all. I also tried doing the same thing to glp, but I dont think alpha composite applies there. If you have any advice on this I'd love to know (seeing as you got it already working. of course feel free to only give me a hint, its more fun that way)

Comment: Well, there's two ways to do it.  One is to apply it on the background before you paint anything.  The other is to set windows opacity level ;)

Comment: @user3670987 Added additional example

Comment: I do have a question after that, assuming I'm experiencing a problem where I only want one popup at a time, but I instantiate a bunch constantly, what can I do in this code or the code in question to alleviate that?

Comment: Basically, you could use a a single threaded executor service hitch would be used to show one message at a time. You'd basically change the show method accordingly