# Netbeans Creating Twine-Style Editing Window

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, menu, nodes

I'm making a node based editor similar to Twine in Netbeans, and I am trying to create a popup menu where the information can be edited when I select a node.
I'm having trouble creating a component that can appear like this:

[image: popup window sample]

Comment: *"Have everything behind fade to black" can be achieved through the use of a `GlassPane` or `JLayer`

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982863/secure-desktop-mode-effect-for-java-application/12983564#12983564) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127422/inner-transparent-selection-window-in-java-using-glasspane/12127579#12127579) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215415/create-an-transparent-rectangle-over-blurred-background-in-jframe/23232618#23232618)

Comment: As to the popup window, there are any number of possible solutions, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841518/how-to-pop-up-a-text-boxor-tooltip-via-script-in-java/23841643#23841643) might work

Comment: Maybe an [`Outline`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36478993/230513) in a modal dialog?